# Flex grid non editable column

Tags: vb6

I don't want to edit some of the column in flex gird.

```
Flex Grid

column1, column2, .... column35
```

i want to edit from column1... column10 only, remaining columns i don't want to edit or type.

How to do in vb6.

Comment: Please give some more information, example code, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MS Flex Grid was designed for displaying data and not editing.  If you need to edit cell data you can accomplish it using the Flex Grid using an approach of superimposing a textbox at runtime to capture user data entry and set the "Text" property of the cell in code.  Otherwise you can choose to use a different control.

Here are some examples of the aforementioned approach:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241355

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_edit_flexgrid_control.html

Answer (score 0):

I've made a special user control in VB6 to an editable grid. If you want I can send you a copy.

The code I use to enable to edit a cell is the follow:

```
Private Sub fg_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Dim Cancel As Boolean
    Dim Idc As Long
    Dim x

    If KeyCode = vbKeyEscape And Shift = 0 Then
        If Not fgLocked Then
            If fgRowChanged Then
                RaiseEvent BeforeRestoreBuffer
                For Idc = 1 To UBound(fgBuffer)
                    x = fgBuffer(Idc)
                    fgValues(Idc, fg.Row) = x
                    If fgColFormat(Idc) = "*" And fgBuffer(Idc) <> "" Then
                        fg.TextMatrix(fg.Row, Idc) = "*******"
                    ElseIf fgColFormat(Idc) = "RTF" Then
                        fg.TextMatrix(fg.Row, Idc) = Format(fgBuffer(Idc), "")
                    Else
                        fg.TextMatrix(fg.Row, Idc) = Format(fgBuffer(Idc), fgColFormat(Idc))
                    End If
                Next
                fgRowChanged = False
                RaiseEvent RestoreBuffer
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyReturn And Shift = 0 Then
        NextCell
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyF2 And Shift = 0 Then
        If Not fgLocked Then
            If fgColFormat(fg.Col) = "RTF" Then
                CellEditBig fgValues(fg.Col, fg.Row)
            Else
                CellEdit fgValues(fg.Col, fg.Row)
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyF2 And Shift = vbShiftMask Then
        If Not fgLocked Then
            CellEditBig fgValues(fg.Col, fg.Row)
        End If
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyDelete And Shift = 0 Then
        If Not fgLocked Then
            RaiseEvent BeforeDelete(Cancel)
            If Not Cancel Then
                If fg.Rows = fg.FixedRows + 1 Then
                    fg.AddItem ""
                    If fgRowNumber Then fg.TextMatrix(fg.Rows - 1, 0) = fg.Rows - 1
                    fgValues_AddItem ""
                End If
                fg.RemoveItem fg.Row
                If fgRowNumber Then Renumera
                fgValues_RemoveItem fg.Row
                LoadBuffer fg.Row
                RaiseEvent AfterDelete
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyInsert And Shift = 0 Then
        If Not fgLocked Then
            RaiseEvent BeforeInsert(Cancel)
            If Not Cancel Then
                fg.AddItem "", fg.Row
                If fgRowNumber Then Renumera
                fgValues_AddItem "", fg.Row
                RaiseEvent AfterInsert
            End If
        End If
    Else
        RaiseEvent KeyDown(KeyCode, Shift)
    End If
End Sub
```